# MySQL aliasing subqueries

Tags: mysql, sql, aliases

I have a table consisting of two columns only: id1 and id2. The following query in MySQL works just fine:

```
(select id1 as id, count(id1) as cnt
from my_table 
group by id1)
union all
(select id2 as id, count(id2) as cnt
from my_table
group by id2)
```

If I want to use above query as a subquery, I need to alias every derived table - below code gives an error ("every derived table must have it’s own alias"):

```
select id, cnt from
(select id1 as id, count(id1) as cnt
from my_table 
group by id1)
union all
(select id2 as id, count(id2) as cnt
from my_table
group by id2)
```

But I can't find out the correct syntax to alias the derived tables. I was experimenting with adding and removing parenthesis, but no luck so far. For below query I just get generic SQL syntax error:

```
select id, cnt from
(select id1 as id, count(id1) as cnt
from my_table 
group by id1) as tab1
union all
(select id2 as id, count(id2) as cnt
from my_table
group by id2) as tab2
```

Later on I will want to do something more with this subquery rather than only selecting id and cnt, but it's simplified scenario to find correct syntax for aliasing subqueries.

Comment: I'm sure it's not "it's" !

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below: since you union all the result so you need just one alias

```
SELECT id, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT id1 AS id, COUNT(id1) AS cnt
    FROM my_table 
    GROUP BY id1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id2, COUNT(id2)
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY id2
) AS tab;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to round out this question, here is the syntax you need to union two derived tables:

```
SELECT id, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT id1 AS id, COUNT(id1) AS cnt
    FROM my_table 
    GROUP BY id1
) AS tab1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, cnt
FROM
(
    SELECT id2 AS id, COUNT(id2) AS cnt
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY id2
) AS tab2;
```

### Demo

You need explicit select statements for *each* component of the subqueries in the `UNION`.  Of course, the answer by @fa06 is what you should use, but if you needed to go down this road, the above is how you would make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation!